# Prove $K = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^2: x^2y^3+x^3y = 2\right\} $ monotonous decreasing at $(1,1)$

Tags: calculus, functions, proof-writing, curves

Given the curve

$$K = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^2: x^2y^3+x^3y = 2\right\} $$

How can one prove that $K$ goes through the point $(1,1)$, is locally solvable by $y$ there and that the solution is monotonically decreasing?

This is what the grapher shows, but I don't know what to do to prove the above.

[image]

Comment: The usual approach here is to use the [implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem)

Comment: You have a cubic in $y$. Consider its discriminant to determine when there is a unique real $y$ corresponding to a given value of $x$.

Comment: You "prove" that the curve goes through (1,1)  by inserting $x=y=1$ into your curves equation, and see if the equation is true. It's true because $1*1+1*1 = 2$